# How can I install the latest z3 version in circleci?

Tags: z3, circleci

The default Z3 version circle has is too old (`apt-get install z3` gives `z3-4.4.1`)
I also tried to add the below in `config.yml` but it did not installed z3 on the path. 
Any other suggestions? Any link from an existing circle setup that is using a new version of `z3` would be appreciated!

Thanks, 
Niki

```
      - run: 
          name: Install z3 
          command: |
            wget https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/releases/download/z3-4.8.7/z3-4.8.7-x64-osx-10.14.6.zip
            unzip z3-4.8.7-x64-osx-10.14.6.zip
            rm -f z3-4.8.7-x64-osx-10.14.6.zip
            cp z3-4.8.7-x64-osx-10.14.6/bin/libz3.a /usr/local/lib
            cp z3-4.8.7-x64-osx-10.14.6/bin/z3 /usr/local/bin
            cp z3-4.8.7-x64-osx-10.14.6/include/* /usr/local/include
            rm -rf z3-4.8.7-x64-osx-10.14.6
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it! Needed to `wget` the ubuntu instead of the `osx` release!